# Shape Android Studio

Tags: xml, mobile, reshape

tenho uma dúvida, seria possível criar um shape no android studio como este do modelo ? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se Shape pra você significar um layout, sim. Tem como.

Comment: shape é o background por trás da ImageView.